# Export function in component controller

Tags: joomla-3.x

[image]**Excel sheet shows admin template . how to exclude admin template in excel sheet ?**

```
public function export($filename = 'export.xlsx') {

    $sch_id = $_GET['id'];

    ob_end_clean();
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filename) . ';');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; ' . _ISO);
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');

    $sql_query = 'SELECT 
                        cat.title,sch.*
                    FROM
                        jbt7r_scholarships_ AS sch
                    LEFT JOIN
                        jbt7r_categories AS cat ON cat.id = sch.category
                    WHERE
                        sch.id = ' . $sch_id;
    $database = & JFactory::getDBO();
    $csv_save = '';
    $database->setQuery($sql_query);
    $rows = @$database->loadAssocList();



    $table = '';
    $table .='<table><tr><th>Scholarship Name</th><th>Expire Date</th><th>Category Name</th><th>Description</th></tr>';

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $table .= "<tr>";
        $table .= "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        $table .= "<td>" . $row['expiredate'] . "</td>";
        $table .= "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
        $table .= "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
        $table .= "</tr>";
    }

    $table .= '</table>';
    echo $table;
}
```

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific as to what your issue is. As it stands, what you've provided is not much to go with.

Comment: In my excel sheet admin menu displays such as menu, dashboard,global configuration etc.,

Comment: Which excel sheet ? Where did you get it ?

Comment: In 'export.xlsx' ....

Comment: instead of table this function returns admin template

Comment: And where/how do you access/run the export function ?

Comment: Inside component [ controller.php ]

Comment: from view/tpl/default.php

Comment: Maybe, you should close the app at the end of your funnction ;)

Comment: how to close app?

Comment: `JFactory::getApplication()->close();` You should also take a look at following question: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017154/how-to-add-custom-header-data-in-joomla)

Comment: Addition: Due to MVC paradigma, you should not create markup in a controller.

Comment: Thanks @Nils Ruckmann ... its working after close the app ... Thanks a lot

Comment: Please write an answer / close the question.

Comment: My fully implemented, stand-alone custom module may be useful to developers who are generating excel documents /.csv files on the fly from database data. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24314/12352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the app to prevent it from default rendering process

```
  JFactory::getApplication()->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the export function from a url try adding &tmpl=component in the url (check if your template has a component.php file) this file only show the main component without template or modules