# How to get data from core components and modules formatted as JSON?

Tags: joomla-3.x, ajax, json

As I would like to use a front-end JavaScript framework within Joomla I would like to know what's an efficient and maintainable, structured way of accessing data from core components (such as `com_content`) and core modules (such as `mod_menu`) and exposing them as JSON.

I've searched the web and found `com_ajax` (Joomla's AJAX interface) to expose some JSON from modules and plugins.

However, I tried that using the following GET request:

`index.php?option=com_ajax&module=menu&format=json`

And it responded with:

`{"success":false,"message":"Method getAjax does not exist.","messages":null,"data":null}`

Thus `mod_menu` does not itself seem to expose any data as JSON (as a built-in function). Should I then implement that `getAjax` method myself?

For core components such as `com_content` I thought of overriding either View or Controller.

Overriding a `View` certainly seems like a relatively *easy* way to expose some data as JSON and it should probably work for both `mod_menu` and `com_content`. Though a overriding a `Controller` would probably execute with less overhead.

Or should I just directly query the database for data within `com_content` and `mod_menu`'s tables? E.g. put those database queries in a custom component?

Is there some 'Joomla approved' way (a best practice) to do this?

Comment: What data are you expecting/hoping to extract from those core components/modules?  Yes, if you are just looking for result set data, just set up some ajax calls that return the data from specific queries.  This recent post which uses best security practices with Joomla's com_ajax should inspire: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24287/12352

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to extract some blog data from com_content and the menu items from mod_menu so I could use it in a frontend JavaScript framework to make a Joomla-based PWA (Progressive Web App). And then just keep using the backend for blog entry stuff and such. Though it 'feels' like I'm "working against" Joomla by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Only components that specifically provide a JSON response are accessible in the JSON format. Modules are not (by design) directly addressable hence you can not call them directly, therefore, no JSON format option.

You could build a plugin to gain access to the data you wanted but that would be a 100% custom built option.

Comment: Good on ya, Shayne.  Good to see you posting.  I hope we see more of you here.