# Library with namespace and autoloader example

Tags: joomla-4, autoload, namespace

I want to make a namespace for my Joomla components, but I can't find a clear example.

I want to declare multiple classes in my namespace and use autoloading.

For example:

```
namespacebas\xml
namespacebas\db
namespacebas\tools
```

Then I want to only have to put `use namespacebas\xml;` at the top of my php file.

Can anyone help me with a simple example which I can easily customize to my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer finaly i greated an example on github for who is intrested:
https://github.com/basd82/joomla_libarary

Comment: Answers must never be solely comprised of a hyperlink.  Please post a static solution here so that a deadlink doesn't present a deadend to researchers.

Comment: @mickmackusa it are muttipel files en plugin script i don't i should post all the code here!

Comment: I haven't yet clicked your link to see how much code there is, but it is a hard, long-lasting rule that link-only answers are not complete answers -- because they are prone to breakage over time.  Please post your snippets as separate/named code blocks in your answer.  For example:  https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24314/12352